# jQuery UI-draggable: when container has scroll window becomes scrollable too

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 3 high .sortable divs.
Each .sortable div contains several divs, that can be dragged to any of the .sortable divs.
As both kinds of divs are quite high, each .sortable div needs a scroll, and the whole page too.
When i want to drag an item from the last div to the first one, the scroll inside of each of the .sortable divs works, but the scroll of the whole page does not. Ans it gets impossible to the achieve the task.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>sortable demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .sortable {
            border: solid;
            width: 700px;
            height: 600px;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .item {
            float: left;
            border: solid;
            width: 250px;
            height: 550px;
            margin: 5px;
            background-color: black;
            opacity: 0.5
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="sortable">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sortable">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sortable">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(".sortable").sortable({
            connectWith: ".sortable"
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```